# Is it possible to parameterize the values in stage condition Azure DevOps Yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, true))
```

*Is it possible to parameterize 'true'. as we have 100's of projects. we need to have one parameter which we can modify to reflect it in all the projects.*

Comment: More sample code would be helpful but I will try and post an answer

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comment above more details would be helpful but I believe based on your scenario yes you can parametrize a stage.  Would recommend doing an if condition before the stage is loaded based on your parameter. This would avoid the compilation issue of a parameter being read into the stage name.

```
 - ${{ if eq(parameters.value,true) }} :
  - stage: xyz
```

Comment: If downvoting please provided a reason why.